# Transparent background for IME UI in android

Tags: android, service, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to implement (yet another!) input method.  I started with the soft keyboard example, which implements uses and extension of the KeyboardView object, which extends View. I want to extend View in a completely different way, so I put the following in my input.xml.  Note that my objective is to have a transparent surface for the UI.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.diffstrokes.ime.StrokeView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:cacheColorHint="@null" >
</com.diffstrokes.ime.StrokeView>
```

The activity that calls the IME is obscured by a light gray background. If I change my background color to a translucent red, for example, I see a few lines of pixels of gray above the view background.  Where is this background coming from, and how can I get rid of it?

---

I tried to use a LinearLayout instead of a view.  The LinearLayout contains two View tags.  In my onCreateInputView() function I inflate the LinearLayout with the following:

```
LinearLayout llo = 
(LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.dslayout, null);
```

The `onCreateInputView()` completes without problems, but at some point I get an exception, as in the following log:

```
 06-12 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 06-12 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
 parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. 06-12
 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:2117) 06-12
 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:2012) 06-12
 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):     at
 android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1992) 06-12
 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):     at
 android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.setInputView(InputMethodService.java:1105)
 06-12 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):   at
 android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.updateInputViewShown(InputMethodService.java:963)
 06-12 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):   at
 android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindowInner(InputMethodService.java:1318)
 06-12 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):   at
 android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindow(InputMethodService.java:1293)
 06-12 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):   at
 android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService$InputMethodImpl.showSoftInput(InputMethodService.java:392)
 06-12 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):   at
 android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.executeMessage(IInputMethodWrapper.java:176)
 06-12 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):   at
 com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
 06-12 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):   at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-12
 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):     at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 06-12 15:17:01.350:
 E/AndroidRuntime(14002):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806) 06-12
 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-12
 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):     at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 06-12 15:17:01.350:
 E/AndroidRuntime(14002):   at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 06-12 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):   at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 06-12
 15:17:01.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14002):     at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I inflate a view, this doesn't happen.  Can anyone explain why?

Comment: <com.diffstrokes.ime.StrokeView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:cacheColorHint="@null" >
    </com.diffstrokes.ime.StrokeView>

Comment: How do I make the XML code show up with normal formatting?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Answering my own (secondary) question: LayoutInflater "instantiates a layout XML file into its corresponding View objects [see LayoutInflater documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html). This leaves me with my original question: what is the object obscuring the workspace, underneath my transparent view.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but I figure I'd post an answer in case anyone runs into this issue when trying to create a transparent IME. Please see my answer to a related StackOverflow question for an explanation of what the light gray (or white) background is, and how to properly create a transparent IME: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20319466/1160216