# Transparent InputMethod for Android

Tags: android, transparent

Trying to make an Android InputMethod that is transparent - i.e. the underlying content shows through to the keyboard that I am developing.

I've been able to make the View that I pass to the system transparent - I think - but there seems to be something underneath my view that is solid white - and obfuscating the underlying content.

It is definitely possible, these guys do it:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aitype.android.tablet.p&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5haXR5cGUuYW5kcm9pZC50YWJsZXQucCJd

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing, and am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out! Not sure if this is how the guys in your play store link did it, but this is what worked for me. Also, I realize this post is over a year old, but I'm still answering it just in case someone else out there discovers this when trying to create a transparent keyboard.

The "something" under your view is actually nothing - it's empty space. Your keyboard pushed the entire view up and out of the way to make room for its height, leaving empty white space behind. Your transparent keyboard let this white space show through.

Here's the solution: instead of returning your view in onCreateInputView, return it in onCreateCandidatesView. That's the view that normally lives above the keyboard and lists the autocorrect suggestions. But you're going to use this to house your actual keyboard.

The reason you want to have your keyboard be a candidates view is because the input view most often pushes the underlying view up. Individual apps can decide how they want to behave when a keyboard is shown via android:windowSoftInputMode and the input view respects their preference, but the candidates view always uses adjustPan.

From the docs: "Note that because the candidate view tends to be shown and hidden a lot, it does not impact the application UI in the same way as the soft input view: it will never cause application windows to resize, only cause them to be panned if needed for the user to see the current focus." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html

So, return your transparent view from onCreateCandidatesView, return null from onCreateInputView and make sure to call setCandidatesViewShown(true) so your candidates view shows up (I call it in onWindowShown).

Comment: Doesn't this mean the same thing will happen if the app's input is at the bottom of its layout? To avoid obscuring it, Android will pan the app so it goes off the top of the screen, leaving a blank behind the keyboard.

Comment: That's what it'll do if you use onCreateInputView. As I explained, onCreateCandidatesView behaves differently. Experiment a little with it; you'll see that the input stays right where it is (unless, maybe, it's in a vertical scrollview. I haven't tried that)

Comment: No, if you use an input view, Android will pan or resize the window according to the activity's settings. According to the documentation you quoted, the candidates view will cause the activity "to be panned if needed for the user to see the current focus".

Comment: I think when you use onCreateCandidatesView, panning only happens if the thing that has focus is in something lile a scrollview. It won't cause any change to the layout, which would be required to do the panning you're describing (the panning that onCreateInputView would do)

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I hacked CandidateView in order to show pop-ups above the keyboard. Pop-ups only display when  inside the bounds of KeyboardView or CandidateView. I've tried to get around this hack by having KeyboardView in a layout filling the screen. I've tried at least 3 different ways to make the  background layout transparent but it only shows a blank fill, same as OP. I wonder if this is a security restriction or if there is a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Normally InputMethodServices uses background color which is same with current binding application's background color. If you want to make this transparent, I think you should make it as popup-window structure, not an inputmethod window I think.

Answer (score 0):

It may such easy to make the full screen keyboard layout extra area transparent via java reflection only if you're quite familiar with `InputMethodService`.

the extra area has an id name **fullscreenArea**, you can fetch the area's id, then findViewById() then set its background.

the keyboard look as this before I done my practice :

[image: before appearance]

a giant blank cover the below page.

so after is :

[image: after]

you can see the below page which contained an EditText and others displayed.

here is my code :

```
public static void makeKeyboardTransparent(InputMethodService service) {
    try {
        View decorView = service.getWindow().getWindow().getDecorView();
        final int viewId = fetchInternalRId("fullscreenArea");
        View fullscreenArea = decorView.findViewById(viewId);
        if (fullscreenArea != null) {
            modifyView(fullscreenArea);
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    try {
        Class<?> superClass = service.getClass().getSuperclass();
        Field fullscreenAreaField = superClass.getDeclaredField("mFullscreenArea");
        fullscreenAreaField.setAccessible(true);
        View fullscreenArea = (View) fullscreenAreaField.get(service);
        if (fullscreenArea != null) {
            modifyView(fullscreenArea);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

private static void modifyView(View fullscreenArea) {
    fullscreenArea.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}

private static int fetchInternalRId(String name) throws Exception {
    Class<?> rIdClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$id");
    return rIdClass.getDeclaredField(name).getInt(rIdClass);
}
```

I provided two approach to make the blank area transparent, both of them worked fine in my test, all you need is pass your InputMethodService into `makeKeyboardTransparent()` and see what it can do.